# Expose version of extension in phpinfo() output

Tags: c, php-extension, php-internals, php

When writing custom extensions for PHP, you usually define a version string in the header file of your extension, e.g. something like

```
#define PHP_MYEXT_VERSION "0.1.0"
```

PHP will then use this to provide information about the extension's version when calling `phpversion('myext')` in userland PHP.

However, the version string will not be rendered in the output of `phpinfo()` by default. Some extensions, like ext/json, do have their version listed in the output of `phpversion()` though.

How can the version be exposed in `phpinfo()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define which information is displayed for your extension in the output of `phpinfo()` by providing the `PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION` function in your myext.c file.

Example from [ext/json](https://php-lxr.adamharvey.name/source/xref/master/ext/json/json.c#176):

```
/* {{{ PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION
*/
static PHP_MINFO_FUNCTION(json)
{
    php_info_print_table_start();
    php_info_print_table_row(2, "json support", "enabled");
    php_info_print_table_row(2, "json version", PHP_JSON_VERSION);
    php_info_print_table_end();
}
/* }}} */
```

This will then produce an output like this:

```
json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.4.0
```